# How to keep trailing whitespace with gulp-jade

Tags: html, pug, gulp

My client has scripts to build templates with Jade. We use [gulp-jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade). I run into an issue where trailing whitespace is removed but should be kept. Here is an example of what the template is:

```
p
  span This is the first part of the sentence, 
  strong this part makes a strong point, 
  span and this part concludes the sentence.
```

Since inline HTML elements are whitespace sensitive, after compiling the template, this is what I would expect:

> This is the first part of the sentence, this part makes a strong point, and this part concludes the sentence.

However, this is what is actually compiled:

> This is the first part of the sentence,this part makes a strong point,and this part concludes the sentence.

Notice the spaces missing?

Looking through the Jade documentation, it seems this shouldn't happen. Would this be related to gulp-jade? I tried to look for options about this, I didn't find it.

Please do not suggest CSS solutions, as they do not qualify as a valid solution. HTML already handles this normally, it's a template compilation issue.

NOTE: I can't use markdown in my example, as removing the spaces break the bold/strong part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your jade option object?

Comment: @Urahara: it is pretty bare: `{pretty: true}`. I see nothing in the [Jade options](http://jade-lang.com/api/) that mentions keeping or removing the trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this problem before, solved using [gulp-prettify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prettify). Here's my jade task:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.src)
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(prettify({ indent_size: 2, unformatted: ['pre', 'code'] }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});
```